# Is it safe to change logrotate rotate config? Any risk of old logs being deleted?

Tags: logrotate

I'd like to change the config of `rotate 16` to `rotate 104` for a logrotate config.

Is this a safe operation? Can it potentially mess up the order / loose log entries? Yes I can and should make backups but the question still stands.

The existing config files look like:

```
ls -altr /var/log/syslog*
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   519034 Feb  9 06:25 /var/log/syslog.7.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   536216 Feb 10 06:25 /var/log/syslog.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   539045 Feb 11 06:25 /var/log/syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   529755 Feb 12 06:25 /var/log/syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   534445 Feb 13 06:25 /var/log/syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   550435 Feb 14 06:25 /var/log/syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 16701454 Feb 15 06:25 /var/log/syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  4742821 Feb 15 13:12 /var/log/syslog
```

The fact that these are numbered in a particular order makes me think it may have some indirect dependency on the config.

Comment: There is no "risk" for old logs to be deleted. There is certainty. They **will** eventually be deleted, although you can use a high `rotate` parameter to make them essentially immortal. Archived logs are numbered according to their archive time. I don't think I understand your last paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increasing the count given after `rotate` increases the number of log files which are kept before being deleted or emailed. Your existing logs will remain: the next time `logrotate` runs, `syslog.7.gz` will be renamed to `syslog.8.gz`, etc., `syslog.1` will be compressed and renamed to `syslog.2.gz`, and `syslog` will be renamed to`syslog.1`.

You’d only *lose* existing logs if you reduced the count given after `rotate`.